# run a shell script inside the pod

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to write a single line command to run a shell script which is inside the pod

getting a shell for a running container:

```
kubectl exec -it test-pod -c test-container -- /bin/bash
```

directory in the container:

```
cd test/bin
```

script inside the bin:

```
./backup.sh
```

how do I write all this in a single command?

Comment: When you execute `kubectl exec -it test-pod -c test-container -- /bin/bash` you are passing in the command `/bin/bash` which returns the shell. Swap that with `/bin/bash test/bin/backup.sh`

Comment: This didn't work as it throws the error /bin/bash: test/bin/backup.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: Likely you'll need to supply the full path to your shell script. `/bin/bash /full/path/to/test/bin/backup.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`kubectl exec -it test-pod -c test-container -- sh /full/path/to/the/backup.sh`

Comment: While correct, OP's question indicates they are using `bash`  and not `sh`, not to mention there are some differences with how `sh` and `bash` function and a script that works fine under `bash` may not work as expected under `sh`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`kubectl exec -it test-pod -c test-container -- /bin/bash -c "/path/to/backup-script.sh"`